# A complete catalog of 2-state Turing machines?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

For educational purposes, I'm about to start a research project that involves creating a complete database documenting and classifying all 2-state, 2-symbol Turing machines, according to a multiplicity of criteria. Including all rejecting and accepting transitions, there are $28.561$ such machines, a number big enough to make it interesting, and small enough to make it feasible.

How did I get this number? Using Tibor Radó's notation for the busy beaver problem, the number of machines for $n$ states is $[4(n+1)]^{2n}$. Adding all rejecting transition possibilities, you get $[4(n+1)+1]^{2n}$ machines.

I have briefly searched online and found nothing similar, so I am asking here if anybody knows if this has already been done, or not. I am aware that many simplifications are possible, but as I intend to explore every angle (what they generate, what they accept, if and when they halt, etc.), the resulting number of different machines will still be quite significant.

Comment: Cross-posted from http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31101

Comment: I am continuing my line of questioning from the cstheory post; I do not think Tibor Rado's definition of Turing machine is significantly different from the standard one.  Further, I don't think that that 4(n+1)^(2n) is the correct formula for the number of Turing machines.  Keep in mind that a valid DTM (i.e., one that doesn't immediately crash due to containing illegal transitions) must have only two edges emanating from every node.  Finally, I've never heard of a "transducer" in a Turing machine.  I think, in particular, that you should share how you got (4(n+1)+1)^2n.

Comment: Note, I glanced at this but didn't read it fully:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver#The_busy_beaver_game .  I think it is a little confusing that you would try to study Turing machines that are so small; why not use a more standard definition of Turing machines, and examine larger Turing machines (e.g., up to 10 states)?

Comment: Finally, see this:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant .  This is not exactly what you are looking for, but I think it is related.

Comment: Ok one more comment, sorry for the additional afterthoughts:  I think you could easily do as many programs as you wanted to in a database as long as you did it automatically, say with C++ or something rather than by hand.  You could conceivably process the properties of millions or even billions of Turing machines, depending on your parameters and computing power.

Comment: I never said that Tipor Radó's definition deviates significantly from the most common definitions. I was trying to say that I use his notation, as it is particularly useful for my purposes. The formula is in Radó's article: http://computation4cognitivescientists.weebly.com/uploads/6/2/8/3/6283774/rado-on_non-computable_functions.pdf.

Comment: Turing machines as transducers are quite normal.

Comment: The reason I want to investigate so small machines is exactly because you can have a vision of the totally of the set. The general problem of mapping characteristics of larger sets of Turing machines is, as I'm sure you are aware, extremely difficult.